# What are the changes required in build setting when added share extension in app and submit Enterprise build

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8-share-extension

> What are the necessary changes required in build setting when added share extension in app and submitting it to Enterprise distribution.

Answer (score 0):

There are no required build setting changes for any type of iOS extension. However, depending on how you want your app and share extension to interact, there are entitlements and capabilities that you may want to set for your application. You should check out a tutorial. A quick google search gave me these:

http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/share-extension-in-ios-application-overview-with-example/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBC2m8BbcCE

Also, you don't have to submit builds for review for enterprise distribution.